# Can we restrict users from installing apps from Google Cloud Marketplace?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace, restriction, google-cloud-marketplace

I am working on a GCP project and I would like to understand if there is way to **limit/restrict** a group of users or specific users from installing applications from **Google Cloud Marketplace**. For example, can we create an Organizational Policy to prevent users from doing this or is there any other way?

Unfortunately, I haven't found anything useful until now apart from this documentation: [Manage Google Workspace Marketplace apps on your allowlist](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6089179?hl=en&ref_topic=1056395), which I am not sure if it is relevant or affects **Google Cloud** at any level.

Comment: hey there! I am not sure I understand exactly what you want to achieve - can you provide more details about this perhaps? did you give [this](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints) a read?

Comment: Essentially, what the title suggests. I want to restrict users accessing applications from the Marketplace at the project, folder or organizational level or even just for specific users. (So as not anyone would be able to install anything from the Marketplace).

Answer (score 1):

You can use IAM role to achieve this. You can find the beta role in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/access-control).

A more advanced and more complex solution is to create your own [solution catalogs](https://cloud.google.com/private-catalog). But it's not so easy to create and requires time to manage

Comment: Regarding your first suggestion: In essence, if we use basic roles (i.e. project owner/editor and even viewer) in the project level, then these users will still have access anyway. Therefore, from my understanding the only way would be to create custom roles instead, right? 
Regarding your second suggestion: Can Private Catalogs restrict even a project Owner/Editor or Viewer from accessing the Marketplace or again I need to customize the roles? @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: Of course, if you want to manage finely permission by permission, you have to remove the legacy editor/owner role and create a custom role. But you don't need to use custom role in the current case, you can use predefined roles (you can assign multiple roles to a same account) https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-marketplace-roles. The private catalog works only if you restrict the permissions to only the catalogs. If you allow more, the user will be able to go over.